# Static function in abstract class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I've an abstract C# class that is inherited through many classes where I want to add a static function into the generic class.

```
public abstract class A<T>: where T
{
    protected A()
    {
        // setup class A
    }

    public List<T> GetResult()
    {
        return new List<String>();
    }
}

public class B : A<String>
{
    public string FooBar()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Now, I'd like to add a static class to the abstract class A

```
pulic static List<T> GetResults()
{
    var foo = new A();
    return foo.GetResult();
}
```

Now, I'd like to call the new static function through the inherited class

```
B.GetResults();
```

Is something like this possible with an abstract class?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a static method?

Comment: You can call static method only through Type declared it.

Comment: I have a feeling whatever it is you're trying to do here isn't possible. You might have better luck if you explain the situation and why you want to do this and someone can give you a recommendation on how to implement a solution.

Comment: `var foo = new A()` for an abstract class seems to be a rather bad start...

Comment: Your question is *very* unclear, as all kinds of bits of your code don't make sense - such as trying to construct an instance of your abstract class.

Comment: @DmitryMartovoi: Actually, if `GetResults` is defined as a static method on base class `A`, and `B` derives from `A`, you can call the method using the syntax `B.GetResults()`.

Comment: @MartinLiversage: Yes, I would like to emphasize the fact that static method invokes only through Type, but not object.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is unclear because you've given code which is invalid in a number of ways. However, you *can* create a static method in an abstract generic base class, and you *can* call it "via" the name of a derived type... but it's not particularly useful to do so.

So this code works:

```
using System;

public abstract class A<T> where T : new()
{
    public static T CreateInstance()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}

public class B : A<int>
{
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(B.CreateInstance());
    }
}
```

... but the call to `B.CreateInstance()` is *exactly* equivalent to:

```
A<int>.CreateInstance();
```

... and indeed, that's what it's compiled to.

In general I would *strongly advise* against accessing static members via a derived class. So similar, instead of writing `ASCIIEncoding.ASCII`, I'd recommend writing `Encoding.ASCII` - it's clearer what you're using.

Now whether this actually solves your problem or not is a different matter - it's unclear, as you haven't really explained what you're trying to achieve, only the manner in which you were *trying* to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
public abstract class A<T, TSelf> // TSelf name just to clarify here
    where TSelf : A<T, TSelf>, new()
{
    public abstract List<T> GetResult();

    public static List<T> GetResults()
    {
        var foo = new TSelf();
        return foo.GetResult();
    }
}

public class B : A<String, B>
{
    public override List<String> GetResult()
    {
        // Do something....
    }
}
```

Now you can call:

```
List<String> results = B.GetResults();
```

Comment: +1 for quite an out of the box approach